# How to determine the execution time of all functions called during an API call?

Tags: api, go

I built an API in golang.  I want to determine where, in the lifetime of serving a request, I have slow downs. My current solution is to log the duration times for every function in the request call. So, something like this:

```
start := time.Now()
defer func() {
    log.Debugf("duration: %d", time.Since(start).Seconds())
}()
```

Putting the code above in the beginning of every function is cumbersome and clutters the codebase. Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do? Are there tools I can use for this?

I looked at libraries in github but couldn't find a more elegant solution.

UPDATE:

To add to the complication:

1. My APIs calls other APIs and those calls needs to be timed.
2. The APIs are hosted in Heroku and AWS.

Comment: You could profile your application using `pprof`. https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/pprof/

Comment: @Adrian unfortunately, that wouldn't help since my API calls other apis (external to my app). I'll update the question to reflect that. Thanks.

Comment: You could do this in middleware, call time.Now() before the call to next.ServeHTTP(w, r) and log after

Comment: @MadWombat I can certainly time the HTTP handler that way, but what about the other functions which the handler calls? They need to be individually timed.

Comment: As Adrian suggested, profiler could help with that. Profiler should tell you how long your functions take to execute no matter what is going on inside them.

Comment: pprof is a sampling profiler; it doesn't tell you how long things take, it estimates what percentage of the time you're within certain functions. Maybe look into https://blog.golang.org/http-tracing, but generally you'll need to add your own tracing within the app.

Comment: You can do it with decorators. It’s also a large piece of code, but maybe you could make a generator which will generate the file for you

Comment: You can take a look at [X-Ray](https://aws.amazon.com/xray/) also.

Comment: I agree with @JimB. Anyways, if you are interested in something open source for tracing I would suggest you [jaeger](https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-client-go).